# Showing $\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^3=1$

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

In my textbook they asked me to show that 
$$\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^3=1$$

but this is not true, I think.

I put down 
$$\begin{align}
\frac12(-1+\sqrt{3}i)(-1+\sqrt{3}i)(-1+\sqrt{3}i)&=\frac12\left[(1-2\sqrt3i-3)(-1+\sqrt3i\right)]\\
&=\frac12\left[-1+2\sqrt3i+3+\sqrt3i+6-3\sqrt3i\right]\\
&=4\\
\end{align}$$

I checked it twice and I got $4$ what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't cube the denominator

Comment: @DavidPeterson ohhhh thank you!!!

Comment: Also, this is simple with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula.

Comment: thank you @vadim123 i will look at it. i don't know what to do with that yet integrator, but i will look into it. i think you want me to use the $x^3$ as $\sqrt3i$ and i have $-1$ already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now you know your mistake!
>   But there is an alternative way to show that

Consider this cubic
$$x^3-1=0$$
$$(x-1)(x^2+x+1)=0$$
By applying quadratic formula to 
$x^2+x+1=0$

$$x=\frac{-1- i\sqrt{3}}{2} \quad\text{or}\quad x=\frac{-1+ i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Since $x=\dfrac{-1+ i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ is root of $x^3-1=0$ we have

$$\left(\dfrac{-1+ i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^3=1$$

Comment: oh that is cool. what is the name of that second step? that is a really cool way to do it thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: $$\left(\frac{-1+i\sqrt3}{2}\right)=\cos2\pi/3+i\sin2\pi/3=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$$

Comment: oh i had never seen that, really simple!

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)^3=1$$

$$\frac{1}{2^3}(-1+\sqrt{3}i)(-1+\sqrt{3}i)(-1+\sqrt{3}i)=\frac12\left[(1-2\sqrt3i-3)(-1+\sqrt3i\right]$$

$$=\frac18\left[-1+2\sqrt3i+3+\sqrt3i+6-3\sqrt3i\right]$$

Comment: @Integrator it says in $2$ days, but maybe someone will put up a nicer one that is a line or less :)